# boundries of feature that faces each other

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, computational-geometry

I need to find and extract the edges of faced feature to each other.
in other word, each point in one feature which can see the points from other  feature is desired for me.

in my case, I have done several processes on my image and finally I have two features.  I need to use the only edges which faces each other.

[image: [1]]

as illustration:
the image A is the original one and the B has marked with blue line in the edges which i desire to extract for further process.

any idea, algorithm, description is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

For such a configuration, you can use the "bridges" of the global convex hull to split the boundaries.

[image]

Comment: could u more explain. it does not seem as i would do in your picture

Comment: @Mason: yep, your picture is slightly inaccurate.

Comment: this is not accurate cause i did it with hand and i need idea for doing that with matlab , i thought to seperate with bwlabel and then work with regionprop , today i could have some progress and i put my result tomorrow